# Symfony 3 with AWS Client throws AnnotationException ("@http" annotation)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, aws-php-sdk

I'm about to use `KnpGaufretteBundle` in my Symfony 3.0 project, which uses `aws/aws-php-sdk` dependency.

I have configured my services, defined AWS credentials and client as services.

```
<!-- AWS -->
    <service id="app.aws_credentials" class="Aws\Credentials\Credentials">
        <argument>%aws_access_key_id%</argument>
        <argument>%aws_secret_access_key%</argument>
    </service>
    <service id="app.aws_s3.client" class="Aws\S3\S3Client">
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="region">%aws_s3_region%</argument>
            <argument key="version">%aws_sdk_version%</argument>
            <argument key="credentials" type="service" id="app.aws_credentials"/>
        </argument>
    </service>
```

The werid part starts when I run `composer update`, `cache:clear` fails and throws:

```
    [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                                                
         [Semantical Error] The annotation "@http" in method Aws\AwsClientInterface::getCommand() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

`@http` doens't seem to be an annotation that does anything.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: The string '@http' is part of the documentation on a method in that interface and not an annotation.

Comment: @giaour Well, I know that, but still Symfony treats it as annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out some time ago, just forgot to mention here.

Symfony Bundle, provided by Amazon helped, available at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony

I just used services provided by `aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony` composer package, instead of defining them by myself.

Works like a charm :)